# Text area is not working if i keep tiny mce tool bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have put tiny mce toolbar. I am new to use this. Although the tool bar is coming for all text areas, the text area is not allowing to insert any content in it. Please let me know the correct way to implement tiny mce tool bar. And also please let me know how to insert tiny mce for only some of my text areas in the same program

Comment: Post the code what you have tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple, basic initialization setting, that should work ([have a look at this page too](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/multiple_configs.php) and inspect the source):

```
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple",
        editor_selector : "mceSimple"
});
```

If this does not help please post what you tried to initialize your editor.